# Is it possiable to pre-load a component in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Flash-list and video component loads so show 1sec after the app starts on iOS and about 3sec and a lag on Andriod 6 GB RAM. How do TikTok/Insta reels load videos so smoothly? What should I do now? Is there any way to pre-load the whole screen? Or what other good approach? using react-native-video for Video

```
const VideoPlayer = (props: Props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Video
                source={props.video}
                resizeMode="cover"
                repeat
                paused={true}
                style={styles.backgroundVideo}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Using Flashlist

```
const Video = () => {
  const [currentIndex, setIndex] = useState<number>(0);

  const data = useMemo(() => [
    require('./videos/video1.mp4'),
    require('./videos/video2.mp4'),
    require('./videos/video3.mp4'),
    require('./videos/video4.mp4'),
    require('./videos/video5.mp4'),
    require('./videos/video6.mp4'),
    require('./videos/video7.mp4'),
  ], [currentIndex]);

  const renderItem = useCallback(({ index }) => {
    return (
      <VideoPlayer
        video={data[index]}
      />
    )
  }, [data, currentIndex]);

  return (
    <View style={{ height, width, backgroundColor: 'pink' }}>
      <FlashList
        data={data}
        removeClippedSubviews={false}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.id ? item.id : index}`}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        snapToAlignment={"center"}
        decelerationRate={"fast"}
        disableIntervalMomentum
        initialNumToRender={10}
        windowSize={5}
        snapToInterval={height}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
        updateCellsBatchingPeriod={50}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        pagingEnabled
        viewabilityConfig={{
          itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 0
        }}
        onMomentumScrollEnd={(e) =>
          setIndex(Math.round(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y / height))
        }
        estimatedItemSize={20}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: If you're only displaying 1 video at the time on the whole screen using this approach... check your `initialNumToRender` / `windowSize` props.. doesn't make sense... also you wouldn't be storing video's with the app bundle (as you do in your `require()` but pull them from remote with optimised quality per screen size. (sending pixelRatio/width/height) etc. etc.

Comment: @Pim I tried this approach, But still no better results. loading video from a remote uri and the video size is just the screen size of nheight and width of the screen